Get a specific text from a text file output with a value in a column format
I'm trying to get a value from an output sample below using a custom app that I ran on PowerShell/CMD.
The format of the output looks like this:
Upload Hello.zip: 933 of 933 bytes complete
 Id        Scan type  Analysis Status  Application               Microservice  Release    Action  
 11208503  Static     Pending          Test Application Jenkins                Release 4  STARTED 

The text I need to get is the Id number value below, note that this value changes every time I run the app.

for /f %%e in (filename) do set "id=%%e" [new line] echo %id%

Do I have to save this output in a text file first before I declare this command, or should I just append it immediately on the command I use?

Probably not. Try for /f %%e in ('executablename') do… - see for /? for documentation (or thousands of examples on SO)

$string[1,2] -replace ' {2,14}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv | select -Expand Id

It assumes each line is a separate string.

Do I just append this to my command or do I have to save the output first on a text file then convert it to a CSV format? I am running a command to run a scan btw: 'app scan sast start --file C:\uploader\Hello.zip'. after I ran the app, the output shows the example I made. My objective is to basically pull the scan status or results using the ID from that output. Thanks!

@George, instead of $string[1, 2], use (app scan sast start --file C:\uploader\Hello.zip)[1, 2]. If there can be multiple data rows, use (app scan sast start --file C:\uploader\Hello.zip | Select-Object -Skip 1)

@mklement0 Because the property 'Microservice'  is empty we need to limited the regex to 14 spaces to parse it correctly.

@yy Ah, good point - I missed that. I suggest adding this explanation to your answer.


Preface:

The following PowerShell solution is focused solely on extracting the "Id" field value, based on the specific output format (single "Id" value, at the start of the last line); if you need to extract multiple field values or don't want to rely on the "Id" field being the first one, consider using y y's clever ConvertFrom-Csv based solution.


Since the token of interest is the first whitespace-separated token of the last line of your custom application's output, you can use the unary form of the -split operator:
(-split (yourcustomapp.exe ...)[-1])[0]


PowerShell streams the stdout output from an external-program call line by line; enclosure in (...) collects the lines in an array, whose last element (line) can be accessed via [-1].

The unary form of -split splits the resulting line into tokens by whitespace, while also trimming leading and trailing whitespace. [0] then extracts the first element (token) from the resulting array.



It appears that the unary form of -split removes leading and trailing whitespace.  Compare results of -split " now is \t  it`t "with" now is `t  it`t " -split '\s+'`.

@lit, yes, that fact is already mentioned in my answer ("while also trimming leading and trailing whitespace") and this answer's solution relies on it; unary -split behaves like awk's default field splitting.

For this example, what I understand it that if I run my app:
app scan sast start --file C:\uploader\Hello.zip
My command should be something like this?
$test (-split (app scan sast start --file C:\uploader\Hello.zip) | $string[1,2] -replace ' {2,14}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv | select -Expand Id)
Sorry but I'm not really a programmer or someone who scripts so I am new at this.
My objective is to use that ID as a reference to pull the data after the upload completes.

@George: No, with my solution you don't need ConvertFrom-Csv and select; all you need is (-split (app scan sast start --file C:\uploader\Hello.zip)[-1])[0]

I tried running that command but its not working or my app command is not uploading my file to start a scan @mklement0

@George, that sounds like an unrelated problem. Your question and the answers here are focused on parsing the output as shown in your question, assumed to be produced by your external-program call. Do you still see output when your the (-split ...) command? If so, you'll have to redirect stderr output to stdout: (-split (app scan sast start --file C:\uploader\Hello.zip 2>&1)[-1])[0] Also note that this solution assumes that there's only one Id value to extract.

@mklement0 I run the program using powershell as well.

@George, both solutions here indeed assume that you're running PowerShell and calling the solutions from there. I've updated the answer to make that clear.

I dont see the output after running the said command, probably I was thinking if there is a different method to save the output first in a text file then open it and pull the ID value.

@George: The lack of output could be because  your command's output differs from the one in your question. To troubleshoot, do ([string[]] $out = app scan sast start --file C:\uploader\Hello.zip 2>&1). This will capture the output in variable $out (which you can later work with), while also printing it to the display.
